# Displaying Google fonts on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, google-fonts

I need to download Google Roboto Mono font in two languages - Latin and Cyrillic. After I need to draw the text on the canvas.
[ExampleJsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/d32eLofa/) But when I write something in Cyrillic and Latin, only one language is displayed correctly. This is the language that is first in the link: `google: {family: ['Roboto Mono: 500: Latin, Cyrillic']},`
If we put forward the Cyrillic alphabet, it will load, but the Latin alphabet will not.
Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem.

Comment: Your particular Fiddle displays all right in Chrome for me, but does not display any text in Firefox. Anyway, the workaround I used was to force a font subset preload by formatting various characters from different font subsets in an invisible (opacity = 0) element somewhere on the page, before using the fonts to actually draw anything on the canvas. (The problem reported here: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/issues/399)

Comment: @JānisElmeris clear the cache and try this example https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/d32eLofa/23/. I have a result that I need, but I don't think this is a good trick. I set the latency to 300 ms. I was waiting for the font to be downloaded from the dummy element that used it, but if I have a bad internet connection? Is it possible that this trick could not work for me?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that the font will not be loaded. That's why it's just a trick. :) On the other hand, you could have any of the resources (a CSS, a JS) not loading because of connection, and your site would still not work (in another way). I don't know the UI/UX of your project, but a good approach would be if you can load the fonts at the beginning, then some user interaction happens, and only then at some point the fonts are used to draw on canvas. And for absolutely most cases that interaction time will be enough for the font to load. And yes, in your new fiddle I see the text in FF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw to canvas only after Google Web Font is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315787/draw-to-canvas-only-after-google-web-font-is-loaded)